# Flask request data from bootstrap dropdown list button not in received POST

Tags: python, html, flask, python-requests, bootstrap-modal

I am writing a flask-app and as part of the browser based interface, I have elected to use a drop down list, in between two other buttons.  Ideally I want the selection that the user gets from the dropdown to be incorporated into the POST request, that server side code can process.  However for some reason the request data does not include the dropdown selection.  Can not figure it out.  Any suggestions out there ?

```html
<form action = "employee_entry" method = "POST" type="submit"> 

...

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-left:20pt">Last Month</button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Prev Week</button>

    <div class="dropdown btn-group" name = "dropdown_class" type="button submit" value="Today" action = "employee_entry" method = "POST">
      <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" id="date_btn" name="date_btn_name" value = "Today" type="button submit" data-toggle="dropdown" action = "employee_entry" method = "POST"><span class="caret"></span>Today
      </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="date_options" name="options" value="Today">
            <li><a>option 1</a></li>
            <li><a>option 2</a></li>
            <li><a>option 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>


    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Later Week</button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Later Month</button>

...

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The request data can only come from form elements (such as `<input>`, `<select>` etc). You can't populate the request data from an `<li>` element.

Comment: Thanks Matt, managed to create similar effect by using js to create a hidden input element that passed the data through the Request.